# What is the mechanism behind object class in java?

Tags: java

```
class A{}
class Z{}
class S{}

public class Demo6 {

    void fun(A a){
        System.out.println("A reference");
    }

    void fun(Z z){
        System.out.println("Z reference");
    }

    void fun(Object o){
        System.out.println("other reference");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        new Demo6().fun(new A());
        new Demo6().fun(new S());
    }   
}
```

Output of the above code is coming:

A reference

other reference

My confusion is how "other reference" is printing when we are passing 'S' class object. Elaborate the actual mechanism of how 'S' class object is compatible with the "Object" class.

Comment: You could simplify the example by using static methods.

Comment: Make A extend Z and see which one is called. ;)

Comment: ya...i extended Z, its giving A reference and other reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every class has `java.lang.Object` as a parent - even if you don't write `extends Object`, the compiler adds it automatically. To quote [the javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html):

> Class Object is the root of the class hierarchy. Every class has Object as a superclass. All objects, including arrays, implement the methods of this class.

`S` obviously exists, otherwise it wouldn't compile. Then the compiler chooses the most specific method to invoke. `S` does not match the signatures with neither `Z` nor `A`, and it matches the `Object` one.

Comment: Ya 'S' class is existing else it is giving a compilation error.

Comment: Since i am passing 'S' class object and nothing is defined in 'S' class like no variables and methods. Then the address to which the reference of the 'S' class pointing is passed or null will be passed in fun() method argument?

Comment: @Nitish `S` will be passed (a handle to `S`, that is). but not that java is pass-by-value, so you can't reassign the reference

Answer (score 5):

Every class is a subclass of java.lang.Object even if you don't extend it explicitly.

Comment: Succinct, and entirely answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

**S** is a type of **Object**, as every class in Java is a **subclass of Object**.
When Java search for a suitable method **overload** for **fun()**,
**fun(Object object)** matches the argument and hence it is invoked.

Try to take a look at Method Overloading in Java.